# Django better join

Tags: django, join, orm

Here is my models. This is like a sports team org app. Event model is the sports event like a baseball game. Anyone can belong to multiple teams. So, the team member represents the membership to team.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Event(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to get the list of events my teams have.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    teams = TeamMember.objects.filter(member=self.request.user).values('team')
    return Event.objects.filter(team__in=teams)
```

This does work, but I want to make it to a single join. My ORM-fu is not that great.

Answer (score 2):

As [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) says

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships
>   in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind
>   the scenes. To span a relationship, use the field name of related
>   fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get
>   to the field you want.
>
> ...
>
> **It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, use the
>   lowercase name of the model.**

```
Event.objects.filter(team__teammember__member=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Ding ding ding! Thank you!